# λ-cube: Why are dependent types and dependent functions on the same axis?

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus

The lambda cube seems to unify the concepts of dependent types (types that depend on terms) with dependent functions (functions whose return type depends on an argument) into a single axis.

But what is the reason for that? How is the relationship between these two concepts any different than the relationship between type constructors and polymorphism?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Dependent function types, syntactically, are subject to rules that don't apply to dependent types generally; there are models of dependent types that don't model dependent function types. What is the sense of sameness you have in mind?

Comment: @Malice Vidrine I recognise the difference between the two. That is why it seems so odd to me that the lambda cube would put them on a single axis. I am interested in knowing the reason for that, especially since polymorphism and type constructors were put on seperate axis. I guess I should change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following is one of possibly multiple ways of interpreting the lambda cube. One way to think of this is that if $A:*$, then $A$ is a small type, and if $K:\square$, then $K$ is a large type. In particular we have $*:\square$. We describe the cube as follows.

0. ($\lambda_\to$, or $(*,*)$) In the simply typed lambda calculus, the type of a lambda term is given
   $$A : *, B : *,\qquad x:A\vdash t:B\quad\implies\quad \lambda(x:A).t :\Pi(A,x.B) :*$$
   At first this may seem surprising, because $B$ should not be allowed to depend on $x:A$. However, in order to have a dependent type $B$, we need a function symbol, for example, $\texttt{Id}:A\to A\to *$ which is not typable in $\lambda_\to$ because $A\to A\to * :\square$. This means that we can safely write $\Pi(A,x.B) = A\to B$ if we restrict ourselves to this system.
1. ($\lambda P$, or $(*,\square)$) For dependent types we have
   $$A:*,K:\square,\qquad x:A \vdash t : K\quad\implies\quad
   \lambda (x:A).t : \Pi(A,x.K) :\square$$
   For example, we may assign a type to the identity type for the natural numbers
   $$\lambda (x,y:\mathbb N). \texttt{Id_nat}(x,y) : \mathbb N\to\mathbb N\to *.$$
   **We can now answer your question:** it is $\lambda_\to$ which allows us to write and type a dependent function, but we cannot have dependent types without $\lambda P$. For example,
   $$\lambda (x:\mathbb N).\texttt{refl_nat}(x) : \Pi(\mathbb N, x.\texttt{Id_nat}(x,x))$$
2. ($\lambda 2$, or $(\square,*)$) For polymorphic types we have
   $$K:\square, B:*,\qquad \alpha : K \vdash t : B\quad\implies\quad \Lambda(\alpha:K).t : \Pi(K,\alpha.B) :*$$
   For example, we may type the polymorphic identity function as
   $$\Lambda(\alpha:*).\lambda(x:\alpha).x :\Pi(*,\alpha.\alpha\to \alpha))$$
3. ($\lambda\omega$, or $(\square,\square)$) Type constructors can be typed as follows
   $$K,L:\square,\qquad\alpha : K\vdash t : L\quad\implies\quad \Lambda(\alpha:K).t :\Pi(K,\alpha.L) :\square$$
   for example, the type constructor for vectors is typed
   $$\Lambda(\alpha:*).\lambda (n:\mathbb N).\texttt{Vec}(\alpha,n) : \Pi(*,\alpha.\mathbb N\to *)$$

---

As an application of all three axes, we can now write:
$$\Lambda (\alpha :*).\lambda (x,y:\alpha).\texttt{Id}(\alpha,x,y) : \Pi(*,\alpha.\alpha\to\alpha\to *).$$
which requires both $\lambda\omega$ and $\lambda P$, as well as its constructor
$$\Lambda (\alpha : *).\lambda (x:\alpha).\texttt{refl}(\alpha,x) :\Pi(*,\alpha.\texttt{Id}(\alpha,x,x)),$$
which requires $\lambda 2$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find the most helpful way to think of the $\lambda$-cube as representing the 4 variations on term—type interbinding.

- (λ→) Terms may be bound in terms (functions).
- (λ2) Types may be bound in terms (polymorphism).
- (λP) Terms may be bound in types (type dependency).
- (λω) Types may be bound in types (type constructors).

If $x$ may be bound in $y$, then as a consequence $y$ may naturally depend on $x$ (for $x, y \in \{ \text{terms}, \text{types} \}$). The various assignments of $x$ and $y$ correspond to different axes of the $\lambda$-cube. However, the simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus (λ→), is always present (we could alternatively consider a $\lambda$-tesseract, where this too is given as an axis).

In this way, one may see that polymorphism, type dependency, and type constructors are orthogonal concepts.

As an aside, note that it is possible (in the general context of type theory) to talk about type dependency without allowing terms to be bound in terms (for example, the [$\mathrm{Id}$-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory#=_type_constructor) in Martin-Löf Type Theory). It is also possible to consider types that bind terms other than $\Pi$-types (for example, $\Sigma$-types). However, the $\lambda$-cube specifically focuses on functions.

Comment: It might be that I just don't understand type theory enough, but I do not really see how this answers my question. I still do not see how the relationship between dependent types, types that bind terms, and dependent function types, the type of functions whose return type can reference its argument, is any different than that between type constructors and polymorphism.

Comment: @CO5: In terms of the $\lambda$-cube, type constructors regard types that bind types; polymorphism regards terms that bind types; and dependent types (e.g. dependent functions, which are function types whose return type can depend on its argument) regard types that bind terms. Therefore the three concepts are entirely orthogonal, based on different choices of X and Y in "X that can bind Y". Note that the $\lambda$-cube doesn't have arbitrary type constructors, polymorphism, or dependent types: it specifically has type-level $\lambda$-functions, $\forall$-types, and $\Pi$-types, respectively.

Comment: I want to point out that you gave the same description for $\lambda 2$ and $\lambda\omega$. In $\lambda\omega$, types may depend on types. Additionally, I believe you mixed up $\lambda 2$ (system F) and $\lambda P$ (dependent types). (That is unless I am misreading "x may be bound in y" as "x may depend on y"). Also type dependency *does* have a place in the lambda cube, namely $\lambda P$.

Comment: @Couchy: thanks,  was indeed incorrect. "x may be bound in y" may be read as "y may depend on x". My answer was a little unclear, I've rewritten it to hopefully clear that ambiguity. Thanks for the comment.